# Jolt: decimal to string

Tags: json, jolt

I have something like

```
"amount":{
  "value":"=divideAndRound(2,@(1,value),100.0)",
  "value":"=toString"
}
```

The divide and round line gives me a decimal like 120.11, but the toString line turns that into "12011". How do I get "120.11"?

Comment: You don't have warning about duplicated value? Writing as in example you are modifying same value (12011), try to split it for two modify operations.

Comment: @Magda That makes a lot of sense. I'll try your suggestion using a separate "modify-overwrite-beta" operation.

Also, we store this spec into a json file, so a warning is impossible here. How would I normally use jolt and be able to see a warning?

Comment: I am using http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible solution can be:

json:

```
{
  "value": "21001"
}
```

spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "value": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,value),100.0)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "value": "=toString"
    }
  }
]
```

result:

```
{
  "value" : "210.01"
}
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me after Magda's comment